# electron-builder mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have (arm64), need (x86_64)

Tags: macos, electron, arm, apple-m1, electron-builder

I have the following error in the build after trying to build for intel on an m1.

```
node:electron/js2c/renderer_init:73 Error: dlopen(/var/folders/d8/qgbcwv4131s7946ql6ctljt80000gn/T/.com.electron.app.FGco8P, 0x0001): tried: '/var/folders/d8/qgbcwv4131s7946ql6ctljt80000gn/T/.com.electron.app.FGco8P' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have (arm64), need (x86_64))), '/private/var/folders/d8/qgbcwv4131s7946ql6ctljt80000gn/T/.com.electron.app.FGco8P' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have (arm64), need (x86_64)))
    at process.func [as dlopen] (node:electron/js2c/asar_bundle:5:1810)
    at Module._extensions..node (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1205:18)
    at Object.func [as .node] (node:electron/js2c/asar_bundle:5:2037)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:988:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:829:12)
    at c._load (node:electron/js2c/asar_bundle:5:13343)
    at i._load (node:electron/js2c/renderer_init:33:356)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1012:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Applications/App…ajarenderer.js:9:23)
```

I am using:

```
"devDependencies": {
        "@electron/rebuild": "^3.2.9",
        "electron": "^21.3.1",
        "electron-builder": "^23.6.0",
        "electron-notarize": "^1.2.2"
    },
```

On node `v18.13.0`

Could this be a problem with my zsh? or my nvm? or what part of my environment?

I have tried reinstalling my npm packages, deleteing and remaking the package json

Comment: cross compiling usually does not work. https://www.electron.build/multi-platform-build

Comment: Do you know what native dependency you're using that is causing the issue?